# Graphviz seems to think each row in column one is an attribute, can't solve

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, graphviz

I'm pretty new to data science and did some of the courses on codecademy and sololearn. I'm having an issue with graphviz and sklearn. It seems that when it performs a decision tree on my data, it refers to each row in column one as an attribute even though I designated the attributes myself. I don't care about the stats itself right now, I'm just trying to learn how to properly write code to process data.

The error I keep receiving is: Length of feature_names, 303 does not match number of features, 6.

Any help is appreciated!

edit: Should add that I am using this dataset for practice: https://www.kaggle.com/ronitf/heart-disease-uci

```
def warn(*args, **kwargs):
   pass
import warnings
warnings.warn = warn

from sklearn import tree
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import sklearn.linear_model
import matplotlib
import pydotplus
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import Image

csv = pd.read_csv('heart 2.csv', header=0, index_col=False)
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(csv)
labels = dataframe[['cp']]
attributes = dataframe[['sex','trestbps','chol','slope','oldpeak','age']]
attributes_array = np.array(attributes)
labels_array = np.array(labels)

training_data,test_data,training_labels,test_labels = train_test_split(attributes_array,labels_array, test_size=0.2)

model = sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state = 1)
model.fit(training_data,training_labels)
print(model.predict_proba(test_data))

dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(model,out_file=None,feature_names=labels,class_names=attributes)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)
Image(graph.create_png())
graph.write_pdf("heart.pdf")
```

Comment: `attributes` is a dataframe (a 2-d array). Why are you supplying that to `class_names` param?

Comment: Sorry it was originally switched and I was just trying anything to get it to work. With feature_names = attributes and class_names = labels I still get the same error.